# Create PDF from HTML using TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp

Tags: c#, html, pdf, html-to-pdf, html-renderer

I need to convert a well-formatted HTML string to a PDF document.

I found [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp/) DLL that should do what I need,  but it isn't working fine on formatting.

[That's](http://pastebin.com/20zbf83B) the HTML code I'm trying to convert, and viewing it on browser works fine (I've used Bootstrap CSS, that's been correctly referenced as cdn).

[image]

But once converted to PDF this is the result:
[image]

And that's the code I'm using to convert it:

```
        string html = "";

        if (File.Exists(pathIN))
        {
            html = File.ReadAllText(pathIN);
        }

        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();
        PdfDocument pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, PageSize.A4, 60);
        pdf.Save(pathOUT);
```

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe you should try to make up the html to fit on A4. Have you tried printing it to a PDF from your browser? How does the result look?

Comment: it works really fine [link](http://imgur.com/Y7FxXCN)

Comment: Maybe the library is unable to render it correctly. How did you build the html? Is it a simple table or do you use loads of css?

Comment: it's made using bootstrap, [here](http://pastebin.com/20zbf83B) you can find the entire html source

Comment: If the java scripüts are important, let me tell you the rendering engine will not be able to use them.

Comment: actually those javascripts aren't even used

Comment: I'd say its the css

Comment: I could not get this nuget package to work with bootstrap styling. I ended up going with wkhtmltopdf and haven't looked back since.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using https://wkhtmltopdf.org, works well for bootstrap pages.

Comment: I used it with bootstrap and did not work well at all. Bootstrap 5

Answer (score 5):

I also had issues with this when using HtmlRenderer/PdfSharp with Bootstrap controlling the layout.

Although it goes against the grain, I resorted to using tables for the layout. Given that the destination (pdf) was a obviously a fixed width, being responsive was not a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I know its a little late but this can help someone 
The problem with bootstrap is that to align the columns use float: left and pdfsharp cannot read this property instead use display: inline-block and define the width in pixels.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid useless effort to other people, it doesn't work for Bootstrap like the Table even using display: inline-block to define the width. Right side of table is always trimmed, the size unfitting the letter size in my case.

[image: pls see the snapshot in browser and after rendered to pdf for for the Table]